# Importing a List of Comments from Hacker News

Tags: import, web

Consider [this link](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21840140) has a bunch of separated comments:

> [image]

Is there a clever way to import this into Wolfram Mathematica such we end up getting a list of comments (for, say, sentiment analysis inspection)?

Comment: Hacker News has an API (https://github.com/HackerNews/API), this might be easier to use then to directly scrap the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will recursively call the API listed by theDriver and create a Graph of the comments.  The code is at the end of the post.  The syntax for the function is

```
hackerCommentGraph[id, maxDepth, return]
```

where `id` is the numerical post id for the comment page, `maxDepth` determines how far down the rabbit hole to go, and `return` can be `"CommentList"` for a flat list of comments or (default) `"Graph"`.  For the graph, it uses the comment text as a tooltip.

[image]

```
url = StringTemplate @ "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/`1`.json";
processItem[item_] := Block[
    {depth = depth + 1},
    Module[{body, kids, text},
        nVerts++;
        body = URLRead[url @ item]["Body"];
        If[
            Or[!StringQ[body],
                FailureQ[body = Developer`ReadRawJSONString @ body],
                SameQ[body, Null]
            ],
            Return[Null, Module]
        ];
        If[StringQ[Quiet[text = ImportString[body @ "text", "HTML"]]],
            Sow[{item, text}, "vertices"],
            Sow[item, "vertices"]
        ];
        If[depth>=maxDepth, Return[Null, Module]];
        If[MatchQ[kids = body["kids"], {__Integer}],
            Map[
                Function[
                    Sow[DirectedEdge[item, #], "edges"];
                    processItem[#1]
                ],
                kids
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
hackerCommentGraph[parent_,commentDepth_:4,return:"Graph"|"CommentList":"Graph"] := Module[
    {verts, edges},
    {{verts}, {edges}} = Part[
        Block[{depth = 0, maxDepth = commentDepth, nVerts = 0},
            PrintTemporary @ Dynamic @ Row @ {nVerts, " nodes visited"};
            Reap[processItem @ parent;, {"vertices", "edges"}]
        ],
        2
    ];
    If[return==="CommentList",
        Cases[verts, {_, c_String} :> c],
        Graph[Tooltip@@@verts, edges]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Very nice work!

Comment: Very nice indeed! However, there's some dependency issues with the way the function is defined: [see here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/george.w.singer/432763204221994051649358221585585021925752928292.png)

Comment: @George ? don't see what the issue is

Comment: Some of the variables aren’t scoped and so they are blue, but I don’t know how to avoid that since they are Blocked by enclosing functions.  Is that the issue?

Comment: Jason B.: My mistake. I was confused by the red/blue coloring on some symbols and didn't check to see  if the function actually ran!

Comment: Jason B.: Is there a way to convert a graph (when `return` is `"Graph"`) to a list of comments (as if we passed instead `"CommentList"` for `return`)?

Comment: @George, if `g` is the graph, then `PropertyValue[{g, VertexList[g]}, Tooltip]` should give all the tooltips (with `$Failed` for those without a tooltip).

Comment: Jason B.: Thanks. Also: Did you make the animated video you used of the mouse scanning over tooltips with Mathematica, or another program?

Comment: I used [giphy capture](https://giphy.com/apps/giphycapture)

Comment: Perhaps also useful:  Someone has coded a FirebaseLink for Mathematica that may streamline some of the communication https://github.com/keshavsaharia/FirebaseLink I have not used it personally, and it may not streamline very much.